# Singleton on Jpype

Tags: python, kotlin

I am trying to use a kotlin/java singleton from jpype in python. When I try to do anything I get this `TypeError: No matching overloads found for *static*` I tried importing with    `from package import Singleton` and `jpype.Jpackage(package).Singleton`